# Codename one checkbox style

Tags: codenameone

I am trying to change the color of the check box to grey and I only see the text portion of the checkbox control changed the color to grey but the actual check box icon still black.
Please advise how I can change both colors to grey.
Thanks,

```
CheckBox rememberMe = new CheckBox("  Keep me logged in");
rememberMe.setUIID("GreyColor");
rememberMe.setOppositeSide(false);
```

Now I do see the rememberMe checkbox with grey text but the actual checkbox it displays as black bordered box.

Comment: can you please post with some codes?

Comment: Please check the original question. I have updated with the code.

Answer (score 1):

To change the checkbox image you have to go on Constants tab of theme and select the required field of checkedbox and change its default image from theme as shown in attached image[image]

Comment: Thank you tizbn, I have checked the constants and now I do see where I can this.
Thanks again.

Comment: please thumb up and answered if the problem is solved.